# Logic Pro - Remove Leftover Echo

Tags: logic, echo

How do I cancel the leftover echos after I pause a track?  I can mute the track but when I un-mute it's still there.

Comment: bypass the delay plug in that is still feeding back.

Comment: I don't know about Logic, but this feature sounds like I've seen it in some software (could it be Reaper?).


Comment: As far as I understand you correctly, you mean when hitting pause in the middle of the track, echoes, reverbs, etc. keep on going. This annoys me as well since a long time. Hitting pause for the split of a second is an ugly workaround. Nevertheless, @ARRAYEWHY, you should read the SE FAQ and edit your post (tags help!) also make sure to add more detail. Read other questions as a blueprint.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a track with a long reverb or delay with lot of feedback which keeps playing after you press stop, you have to go to a empty place in the arrange window and press play.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific with your question.

Comment: Setting an echo plugin to overkill, playing through, and then pausing leaves the echos trailing almost infinitely instead of total silence.  Anyway, deleting the instrument and un-doing seems to cut it but this was pretty annoying.

Comment: Go through source, insert & bus plugin chains and try to pinpoint which plugin is in a so called feedback loop. It seems that one of the plugins that you are using has too much feedback and keeps feeding itself. When you find the plugin / source that´s doing the feedback loop, turn down the feedback and the problem should disappear.  

Answer (score 0):

Turn the feedback amount down.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this question although don't know of a way to solve it. Basically the OP wants to bypass live processing in the channel strip when the playhead isn't running. . .

Comment: It's either a feature that's been implemented or then it doesn't exist. It's basically "kill all audio when playback isn't enabled".

Comment: stop, then move the playhead manually to a new position? that forces logic to shut up if i remember correctly.

Comment: Nope. You have to hit play for a split of a second...

Answer (score -3):

Turn the speakers off.

Comment: Aw, you guys are no fun!

Comment: Unfortunately, trolls finally found their way to the StackExchange network. Bummer.